# Book, maybe the third in the series, by an author like McFarlane

Tags: story-identification, books

As a child I was big into reading, and very quickly sci-fi & fantasy became my go to genres. A family member bought me a paperback book, that was much larger in size than your average paperback, and I remember scouring bookshops for the other books in the series, as I quickly realised that this was actually book 3 of a much larger fantasy series, and was loath to read it in case it made no sense due to never having read the earlier books.

I have a strong sense of the author's surname being either
McFarlane/MacFarlane or McFarland/MacFarland.

The writing on the cover was blue, and there was this image of a large troll like creature with I think either a castle or forest in the background and knights all around it.

If this sounds familiar to anyone, I would be very keen to know so I might get hold of this series to read it.

Comment: When were you a child? Do you remember anything about the plot?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a child, so we don't know what timeframe to consider.  Approximately what year was this?  Also, can you recall anything about the setting and plot?  Was it a single protagonist or a group?  Was it a quest, or a sucked-into-a-fantasy-world type plot?

Comment: FWIW, ISFDb records only 52 novels written by someone with a last name starting with "McFar" or "MacFar."  Only 6 of those pre-date 2014, and none of those are in series (no 2 are even by the same author).

Answer (score 14):

This is a bit of a guess, but it's *close* to several of the points you mention.  In 1998 [Dave Wolverton](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1628), writing as David **Farland** started [*The Runelords*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?6171), a fantasy series that began with [*The Sum of All Men*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?203521) and ended with the eighth book, [*Chaosbound*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1143152) in 2009.  (ISFDb tells me there is an unpublished ninth book, for whatever good that is...)

The third book, [*Wizardborn*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?203501), does indeed have a cover featuring a giant troll-like creature facing a knight in full mail with a forest in the background:

[image: Cover of "Wizardborn", book three of "The Runelords" showing a giant hairy creature with a huge face looking down upon a knight in mail riding a white unicorn. The knight is accompanied by a woman in a purple dress on a brown horse.]

These books are indeed hefty; *Wizardborn* is over 500 page in its paperback printing, while the first two books were over 600.

The difference is that the text is black, not blue, and there's only one knight.  It's possible, however that you're conflating this with cover of the first book *The Sum of All Men*, which does have a group of knights and blue text.

[image: Cover of "The Sum of All Men" (published as "The Runelords") showing a group of ghostly knights and ladies against an autumn forest. A man with a sword is kneeling in the foreground with a woman standing beside him. The lead knight is bestowing a crown of leaves on the man.]

Comment: Doing an image search on Google for "The Wizardborn" does show some variants with bluey-purpley titles.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51162/people-can-transfer-physical-and-or-mental-abilities-to-another-person-through-m?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is David Farland's *Runelords* series. In particular book 3, *Wizardborn*. There are indeed [eight published novels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?6171) in the series.
[image: Cover of Wizardborn by David Farland]

The cover does not have blue text, but it does feature a troll-like creature with a knight and lady.