# Book series involving magical symbols that would be placed on people, causing some aspect of them to be transferred to someone else

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I don't remember a lot of details about the series, but one of the more notable things is that there were these symbols that would be put on people and through a sort of magic, an aspect about them would be taken and put onto someone else.

As an example, it might be a symbol of strength which would drain the strength of the person being used, until they were barely able to muster enough to breathe, but give that strength to someone else.

People who had a ton of these were often superhumanly strong and fast, but they had a large group of people that needed to be cared for because if the person giving the boost died, the boost went away.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and do you recall anything about the cover? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?

Comment: That's a great question, and I wish I had an answer. If I had to guess, I was probably 10-14 when I read this series, which would put it in the area of 2008-2012, but I think it was an older series then. I remember a little bit about the plot of the first book, but it was a kind of generic "hero falls in love with princess and fights evil overlord" kind of plot as I recall. I also recall they had a specific name, something like Crucible of Fallible or something of the sort, and were made mostly of some sort of magic metal.

Comment: So was the story set a in medieval-type world?

Comment: It was, yeah. I really wish I remembered more about it. I'm pretty sure one of the later books had a woman who got dragon wings or something? It's kinda blurry because I was an avid reader at that time and read a lot of fantasy stuff.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate. That doesn't mean that it's a bad question, just that we've had it before. This lets us associate the questions in the system, and will prevent additional answers, but you will still keep votes if this is voted up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be David Farland's *Runelords* series as per [People can transfer physical and/or mental abilities to another person through magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51162/people-can-transfer-physical-and-or-mental-abilities-to-another-person-through-m?rq=1).

> In Farland's world, there exists a magic that allows one person to take a physical or mental quality from another.
>
> For example, a common man can grant his strength to his Runelord, living out his days as weak as a baby, while the Runelord becomes twice as strong. Noble children receive gifts from their subjects at birth: beauty, eyesight, brawn, wit or intelligence, hearing, and so on. In return, the Runelords use their talents to govern their people and defend them in times of danger.
>
> The givers of the gifts, called Dedicates, live in luxury, pampered by full-time attendants -- but without whatever qualities they bestowed upon their lords.
>
> So a woman who gives her beauty to a newborn princess lives out her days as a dried-up hag. A man who bestows his flexibility on his king becomes forever creaky and stiff. A gift of sight leaves one blind; a gift of wit leaves one a drooling idiot.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is it, thanks! I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to hunt it down.

Comment: @ThatOneGuyYouKnow: I remembered this one coming up before, so I quickly looked through the "Related" answers on the side. ^_^ If you click through, and look at the Linked answers, this is far from the first time this one has come up. Problem is, you often don't know that until after you've submitted your question.